# How do I write a code to create data table like kendo UI in angular by angular material or native elements?

Tags: angular, datatable, kendo-grid, ag-grid

I'm looking for an interactive data table in angular with abilities like what kendo UI, ag-grid and etc has.

I'm currently using angular material data table and it is enough for me but in the future I need more features and I'm sure it wouldn't be enough for me.

But my question is about creating such data table or data grid with kendoUI and ag-grid features.
How do I start?

Please note that I'm not looking for exact code. I need general advice to start writing code.

What is your idea?

Comment: Q: How do I start?  A: Purchase Kendo-UI?

Comment: Kendu UI, ad-grid and etc are all modules. You can see their codes in GitHub and create your own module, the use it at any part of your application.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

There is already a whole documentation about how the get started with kendo: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/getting-started

Comment: @paulsm4 There is no legal way for my nationality to purchase Kendo-UI because of sanctions.

Comment: @sevic Take it easy and think about what I asked. I didn't start yet but I'm collecting some initial information generally. I'm looking for a general guide not exact code

Comment: It sounds like you need to look at open source alternatives.  You literally have scores of options!  SUGGESTION: Look at a JS UI framework (like Angular2 or ReactJS), then see what data grid options are compatible with that framework.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks a lot. I'll research about it. But mostly I intended to start myself coding.